# Illustrator CS6 - All stroke options in right gradient panel are unusable

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, cs6

So I have a basic 50 pt line selected, go over to the right to open the Gradient panel, but the stroke option - the word stroke and the three boxes next to it - are greyed out and unclickable. I've searched the internet, tried doing different random things in the program (as I am brand new to it), and even tried uninstalling and reinstaling the program but nothing seems to work. It seems as if this option is permanently disabled, which makes no sense. Someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply a gradient to the stroke before you can change the gradient stroke options.

After all, what should the options do if there's no gradient to adjust? Granted Adobe could have made them automatically apply a gradient to the stroke, but that may be *way* too intuitive for Adobe.

[image: gradient strokes]

Comment: Exactly, I thought "stroke box" was the box I couldn't click (durrr).  When you put it like that it seems so obvious, thanks.

Comment: @vcg27 Don't feel bad; we all miss the obvious sometimes. At least you asked for help instead of giving up. :)